# Javascript chunky monkey algorithm code break down?

Tags: javascript

I need a help on breaking how does this code works?

```
    function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
      var newArr = [];
      while (arr.length) {
        newArr.push(arr.splice(0,size));
      }
      return newArr;
    }
chunkArrayInGroups(["a","b","c","d"],2);
```

I dont understand how while(arr.length) gets stop and what this whole code is doing. Please break this down.

Comment: It stops when the array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

[Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) modifies the original Array. When it is called inside while loop, It keeps shortening the original array and after a few iterations, `arr.length` becomes 0 and evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.splice(0,size)
```

`Array.splice` will remove elements from index `0` up till `size` and return them as a new array.

```
newArr.push(arr.splice(0,size));
```

The returned array is then pushed to `newArr`.

```
while (arr.length)
```

`Array.splice` will also mutate the original array so the `arr` will eventually becomes empty and the loop will end.

Answer (score 0):

`while (arr.length)` executes until the array is empty, because when it's empty, `arr.length` equals `0` and it's treated as `false`.

Answer (score 0):

while array count is "available" push into newArr (and also remove the certain item of it from the root array) when all is done, return it